# Regex that allows strings with specific symbols

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a regex in JavaScript that will pass only for the strings that have the following characters

`a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _, -, ., Spaces, ', ? and &`

I tried `/[\w-\.\s\'\?\&]+/` but when testing it against the `re.test("*dfs*d")` it returns true.

Comment: [`/^[\w.\s'?&-]+$/`](https://regex101.com/r/qT0yZ8/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew cheers mate!